# Getting input from users command and using .equals

Tags: java

Im trying to read the users input from the command box of my program and based on what the user enters into this command box the program should output appropriate messages. For example when the user enters quit the program is supposed to stop and I have implemented this correctly. SO what I am trying to achieve is when the users doesnt enter the words :"QUIT", "ROLL","property", "Buy" , "help" "done ,"balance" the program should displau an error message. 
I need the command to work simultaneously so that if any 7 commands entered an appropriate message is returned

Here is my code so far:Thanks ,

```
private void echo () {
        String command ;
        String command2;
        ui.display();
        ui.displayString("ECHO MODE");
        do {
            command = ui.getCommand();
        ui.displayString(command);
        } while (!command.equals("quit"));
        {
            ui.displayString("The game is over.");
        }
        do{
            command = ui.getCommand();
            ui.displayString(command);
        }while (!command.equals("help")||(!command.equals("buy"))||(!command.equals("roll"))||(!command.equals("done"))||(!command.equals("property"))||(!command.equals("balance")));
        {
            ui.displayString("Please enter a valid command");
        }


        return;
```

Comment: What is UI? Add more substance to the code and some log output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last do/while's condition looks almost good, but it should be using `&&` instead of `||` : you want to display the error message when the command input isn't the first expected one, and not the second expected one, etc.

A prettier syntax would be to use a `List` of accepted commands and check whether it contains the received command :

```
List<String> acceptedCommands = new ArrayList<>();
acceptedCommands.add("help");
acceptedCommands.add("quit");
// [...]

do { command = ui.getCommand(); }
while (!acceptedCommands.contains(command));
```

Note that the do/while construct is rarely used (altough it can sometime be more appropriate than a standard while) and that you seem to misuse it ; you've used twice that same pattern :

```
do { actions }
while (condition)
{ more actions }
```

This is probably not doing what you want, since the last block isn't part of the do/while but just an anonymous code block, with its own scope but not much else.

After discussion I think you want something along those lines :

```
private void echo() {
    String command = null;

    while (!"quit".equals(command)) {
        command = ui.getCommand();
        if (!acceptedCommands.contains(command)) {
            ui.displayString("Please enter a valid command");
        } else if (!"quit".equals(command)) {
           // handle other commands
        }
    }
    ui.displayString("The game is over.");
    // no need for "return;", it's implicit
}
```

Comment: even when i use && the program seems to only go through the first do/while loop and the second one is ignored so should i be using another type of loop or something like this ?

Comment: The first loop will run until it encounters the "quit" command as it is. I currently can't help you much more because I don't know what behaviour you want. Should it be able to read multiple correct command before you quit? Should it only handle one, except when it is given incorrect commands? You might want to write that down in form of an algorithm before you get to code

Comment: Also, learn to use the debugger of your IDE. Run the program in debug mode, and step-by-step through the execution. As your current code is, it will be obvious that you stay stuck in the first do/while until the command is "quit". You will see the condition being resolved to True each time the command isn't "quit", and the execution flow going back to the do block

Comment: Basically i have a command box within a jpanel where the user may type anything they wish. However if the user types in "quit" the program should output the game is over which works fine for me right now. Another piece i need to add in is if that one of the commands that are entered isnt "buy","done","property","balance","roll,"help" the program should just ouput something like error "this command isnt valid"

Comment: You still haven't told me what should happen if the user enters an accepted command other than quit. In particular I'm wondering if it should then try to handle additional commands, as it will change the control flow a lot.

Comment: So Simply if the users enters something other than quit, balance ,roll,buy, property , help, done the user should receive appropriate error messages if their input is invalid. As these are the only commands the program can accept. so if isnt one of these 7 commands an error pops up , does that make more sense ?

Comment: That I get, but what happens when it is one of the 7 intended commands? I guess you will later add something specific to the command, but what happens after that part? Do you carry on with another command, or does the method stop here?

Comment: yes i will later on add some more specific outputs for the intended commands , however for the moment I am just working on the error message . For example lets say i type in the roll command the program will roll a dice and after that i can enter in another command so the method wouldnt necessarily stop here

Comment: Thanks. This was important, because it decide between two implementations : "while we haven't handled a single command successfully we try to handle a command" and "while we haven't had the quit command we try to handle commands". I'll update my answer soon with an implementation that should be close to your need.

Comment: Brilliant  works all fine now, many thanks for your help !! I really appreciate that cheers